# Notifications disappear as soon as service ends

Tags: java, android, notifications

I've got a service that scrapes a website for data then if necessary gives the user a notification.

The problem I'm having is that the notifications disappear as soon as the service closes (which could be instantly). The below code is all of the notification code the app has. I haven't put in any code to cancel the notifications.

```
public static void CreateNotificationCompat(int notificationID, String link, String title, String text, Context ctx)
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(link));
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
    Resources res = ctx.getResources();

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setAutoCancel(false);

    Notification n = builder.getNotification();

    nm.notify(notificationID, n);
}
```

If it makes any difference (pretty sure it doesn't) i'm using the application context here.

My services is started periodically, processes a website, notifies if needed and then closes.

At the end of my service instead of just calling stopSelf() i sleep for 30 or so seconds and then call stopSelf(). Then the notification stays for 30 seconds and then disappears. Nothing relevant appears in logcat at the time the notifications disappear.

I've only been able to test using ICS so far.

Comment: This should be fine. Generally notifications will only disappear if your application is forcibly killed. I would expect that something is crashing. It would be interesting to see what code you're using to "sleep" (are you actually telling the thread to sleep?) and what thread that's running on. It would also be interesting to try to remove the 30s sleep for experiment's sake and see if the same behavior happens.

Comment: Where is the code that cancels the notifications if you have any? Also FYI you should NOT use direct strings like android.intent.action.* becasue this is a CONSTANT that is available in the Intent class. @user1531605

Comment: If service is requested to stop  "just before" notification is posted, i.e. on same code execution chain, notification would be cleared.

Answer (score 4):

The code you have posted works. I tested it from both an activity and a service on jb, and the notification stays when the components are stopped. I even verified that I could kill the process and the notification stays. Try to strip down the app and see if the problem persists. Specifically check to see that you don't call cancel on the notification by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to forgot check developer manual first. See here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html and look for FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT and FLAG_NO_CLEAR flags.

> I've only been able to test using ICS so far.

That's why simulators are quite useful. Try it. It's part of SDK.

Comment: I did read it, those aren't what i want. Notifications should be able to be cleared by the "Clear notifications" button, so the FLAG_NO_CLEAR won't help. And this isn't an ongoing event. From the docs "It should not be set if this notification is in reference to something that happened at a particular point in time, like a missed phone call.". That's exactly what this is, a refererence to something that happened at a particular point in time.

Though as a sidenote, i did test with those flags on just in case and had the same results. The notifications still disappeared when the service closed.

Comment: Have you checked your code on pre 4.x androids?. Emulator suffices.

Comment: Post the source code of your Service, only the relevant ones, like the creation and the destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the old way on the same device and tell us if it behaves the same way:

```
private static void CreateNotificationCompat(int notificationID, String link, String title, String text, Context ctx) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notify_icon, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    PendingIntent contentIntent;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(link));
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, notificationID,
                notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, title, text,
            contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just aa note this behaviour occurs when startForeground() is used and then stopSelf() is called.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I need to user startForeground and stopSelf, but after stopSelf, I want to keep the notification. While running it cannot be dismissed, but after stopSelf, I want the user to be able to clear it/dismiss it or retouch a button on my notification to restart the service.. Currently, as I could not find another way I plan to post another notification that says "Touch here to start again". What do you think?